# Prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n^{1/n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am stuck with this question which asks me to prove that for all sequences of real numbers $(a_n)$ $$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n ^{1/n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$$ provided that the rightmost limit exists. How would I do this? I cannot use L'Hopital's Rule as $(a_n)$ is a sequence, not a function. Is there a direct way to prove this?

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: I think these are supposed to be nonnegative real numbers.  Suppose $a_{2n}=-1,\ n=1,2,\dots.$  Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n^{1/n}$ doesn't make sense, even though $\lim {a_{n+1}\over a_n}$ may exist.

Comment: Suppose $\lim_{n\to\infty}{a_{n+1}\over a_n}=A$.  Observe that the theorem is true if $\exists N$ such that $n>N\implies a_{n+1}=Aa_n.$  Then modify the argument to take care of the general case.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume the sequences we take are nonnegative.

Let $L=\lim\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$.

Given $\epsilon>0$, we have, for $n$ big
$$L-\epsilon\leq\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\leq L+\epsilon$$
or equivalently
$$(L-\epsilon)a_n\leq a_{n+1}\leq(L+\epsilon)a_n$$
Now iterate! For all $n$ large and all $k$,
$$(L-\epsilon)^ka_n\leq a_{n+k}\leq(L+\epsilon)^k a_n.$$
Fix $n$ for which these inequalities hold. Equivalently, taking $(n+k)$-th roots,
$$(L-\epsilon)^{k/(n+k)}a_n^{1/(n+k)}\leq a_{n+k}^{1/(n+k)}\leq (L+\epsilon)^{k/(n+k)}a_n^{1/n+k}$$
Let $k\to\infty$ and make a sandwich.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $a_n>0$ and suppose the limit on the right hand side exists and is equal to $l.$ The only thing you know is that for $\epsilon>0$, there is an integer $N>0$ such that if $n>N$, then $\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}-l\right |<\epsilon$. Now use a trick: write $a_n=a_N\prod^{n}_{i={N+1}}\frac{a_i}{a_{i-1}}$ and note that each factor in the product satisfies $l-\epsilon<\frac{a_i}{a_{i-1}}<l+\epsilon.$ Therefore, $a_N(l-\epsilon)^{n-N}<a_n<a_N(l-\epsilon)^{n-N}.$ To finish, take the $n^{\text{th}}$ root across the inequality and let $n\to \infty.$

Remark: a slick way to do this is to take logs and use the Stoltz-Cesaro theorem.

Comment: This is essentially the way to derive Stoltz-Cesaro.

Answer (score 0):

Note that 
$$a_n^\frac{1}{n}= e^\frac{\ln(a_n)}{n}$$

Now, set $b_n= \ln(a_n)$ and prove instead that, if $\lim_n b_{n+1} -b_n$ exists, then
$\lim_n \frac{b_n}{n}$ exists and 
$$\lim_n \frac{b_n}{n}= \lim_n b_{n+1}-b_n$$

This is sometimes referred to as Cezaro average (for $c_n:=b_{n+1}-b_n$) and can be proven with Stolz--Cezaro, but it is an easy exercise.